# How to monitor Camel in-flight messages from outside of the process

Tags: java, logging, apache-camel, state-machine

I have a couple of processes, which run for minutes or more, started by an end user, who wants to know how his order is done yet.
What is the recommended way of asking Apache Camel what state a in-flight is, given an message/exchange ID?

As a developer, looking at the log would be sufficient, but since the log can't be shown to the end user, is there a good alternative to building a state-machine, actively fed by steps in the process, to get message state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of two ways of achieving this:

1. Get a hold of the [`InflightRepository`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/spi/InflightRepository.html) through `CamelContext#getInflightRepository()`. You can use its [`browse()`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/spi/InflightRepository.html#browse()) method to get a `Collection` of inflight exchanges, which gives you access to the Exchange ID and the `Exchange` itself.
2. [Use `EventNotifier`s](https://camel.apache.org/eventnotifier-to-log-details-about-all-sent-exchanges.html) to keep a state machine, as you said. Your [`EventNotifier`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/spi/EventNotifier.html) can get callbacks for events like **exchange created**, **exchange completed**, **exchange sent**, etc.

   You could write those events into a database, e.g. an embedded one like [LevelDB](https://github.com/dain/leveldb) or [Sophia](http://sophia.systems/) [via its JNI bindings](https://github.com/andreaTP/sophia-java), or keep the state in memory.

I would suggest method 2, because method 1 is more computation-intensive and slower given that you have to search and filter through the entire repository until you find the exchange you're interested in.

---

**NOTE:** Obviously these solutions work within the same JVM as Camel. If you want expose this data to another system, you'll have to wrap the solution in a service.

Comment: Thanks for both relevant alternatives - Thinking of using #1 for finding orphaned messages, eligble for ternination and #2 for fetching history during and long after processing